# How to copy textfields to another page?

Tags: java, docx4j

I have a document with a text field, so my problem is that i don't get any content with `document.getContents()` or `document.getContent()`?
Is this a limit from the free version or why I don't get anything? The text field is not emty.

The result should be that i can clone the first page to the second page and use merge fields later if this works.

This is my simple code:

```
    public static void main(final String[] args) throws Docx4JException
      {
        final String projectFolder = System.getProperty("user.dir");
        final String filePath = projectFolder + "/files/GetTextfield.docx";
    
        final WordprocessingMLPackage word = Docx4J.load(new File(filePath));
        final MainDocumentPart document = word.getMainDocumentPart();
    
        final Document pageClone = document.getContents();
      }
```

**EDIT:** This is the document as XML

```
    <w:document mc:Ignorable="w14 w15 wp14" xmlns:cppr="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2006/coverPageProps" xmlns:dgm1611="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/drawing/2016/11/diagram" xmlns:xdr="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/spreadsheetDrawing" xmlns:w16se="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2015/wordml/symex" xmlns:wp15="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2012/wordprocessingDrawing" xmlns:wp14="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingDrawing" xmlns:pic="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/picture" xmlns:a1611="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/drawing/2016/11/main" xmlns:a16svg="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/drawing/2016/SVG/main" xmlns:am3d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/drawing/2017/model3d" xmlns:pvml="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:powerpoint" xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" xmlns:dgm1612="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/drawing/2016/12/diagram" xmlns:comp="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/compatibility" xmlns:xvml="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel" xmlns:c173="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/drawing/2017/03/chart" xmlns:anam3d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/drawing/2018/animation/model3d" xmlns:wpc="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingCanvas" xmlns:adec="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/drawing/2017/decorative" xmlns:oda="http://opendope.org/answers" xmlns:a18hc="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/drawing/2018/hyperlinkcolor" xmlns:odc="http://opendope.org/conditions" xmlns:wpg="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingGroup" xmlns:cdr="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/chartDrawing" xmlns:odi="http://opendope.org/components" xmlns:msink="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ink/2010/main" xmlns:cdr14="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/drawing/2010/chartDrawing" xmlns:iact="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/powerpoint/2014/inkAction" xmlns:an18="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/drawing/2018/animation" xmlns:wps="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingShape" xmlns:odq="http://opendope.org/questions" xmlns:w16cid="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2016/wordml/cid" xmlns:dsp="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/drawing/2008/diagram" xmlns:odx="http://opendope.org/xpaths" xmlns:a15="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/drawing/2012/main" xmlns:a14="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/drawing/2010/main" xmlns:c15="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/drawing/2012/chart" xmlns:a13cmd="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/drawing/2013/main/command" xmlns:c14="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/drawing/2007/8/2/chart" xmlns:a16="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/drawing/2014/main" xmlns:odgm="http://opendope.org/SmartArt/DataHierarchy" xmlns:c16="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/drawing/2014/chart" xmlns:dgm="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/diagram" xmlns:thm15="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/thememl/2012/main" xmlns:we="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/webextensions/webextension/2010/11" xmlns:w10="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word" xmlns:ns39="http://www.w3.org/2003/InkML" xmlns:wp="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/wordprocessingDrawing" xmlns:sl="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/schemaLibrary/2006/main" xmlns:ns38="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML" xmlns:w15="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2012/wordml" xmlns:w14="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordml" xmlns:dgm14="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/drawing/2010/diagram" xmlns:c16ac="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/drawing/2014/chart/ac" xmlns:a="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/main" xmlns:b="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/bibliography" xmlns:c="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/chart" xmlns:m="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/math" xmlns:wne="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2006/wordml" xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:cs="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/drawing/2012/chartStyle" xmlns:r="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships" xmlns:cx="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/drawing/2014/chartex" xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" xmlns:pic14="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/drawing/2010/picture" xmlns:w="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main" xmlns:lc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/lockedCanvas" xmlns:wetp="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/webextensions/taskpanes/2010/11">
        <w:body>
            <w:p w:rsidRPr="009670CB" w:rsidR="00CF457B" w:rsidP="009670CB" w:rsidRDefault="00BD5B37">
                <w:bookmarkStart w:name="_GoBack" w:id="0"/>
                <w:bookmarkEnd w:id="0"/>
                <w:r>
                    <w:rPr>
                        <w:noProof/>
                    </w:rPr>
                    <mc:AlternateContent>
                        <mc:Choice Requires="wps">
                            <w:drawing>
                                <wp:anchor distT="45720" distB="45720" distL="114300" distR="114300" simplePos="false" relativeHeight="251659264" behindDoc="false" locked="false" layoutInCell="true" allowOverlap="true">
                                    <wp:simplePos x="0" y="0"/>
                                    <wp:positionH relativeFrom="column">
                                        <wp:posOffset>-256540</wp:posOffset>
                                    </wp:positionH>
                                    <wp:positionV relativeFrom="paragraph">
                                        <wp:posOffset>0</wp:posOffset>
                                    </wp:positionV>
                                    <wp:extent cx="2360930" cy="1404620"/>
                                    <wp:effectExtent l="0" t="0" r="22860" b="11430"/>
                                    <wp:wrapSquare wrapText="bothSides"/>
                                    <wp:docPr id="217" name="Textfeld 2"/>
                                    <wp:cNvGraphicFramePr>
                                        <a:graphicFrameLocks/>
                                    </wp:cNvGraphicFramePr>
                                    <a:graphic>
                                        <a:graphicData uri="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingShape">
                                            <wps:wsp>
                                                <wps:cNvSpPr txBox="true">
                                                    <a:spLocks noChangeArrowheads="true"/>
                                                </wps:cNvSpPr>
                                                <wps:spPr bwMode="auto">
                                                    <a:xfrm>
                                                        <a:off x="0" y="0"/>
                                                        <a:ext cx="2360930" cy="1404620"/>
                                                    </a:xfrm>
                                                    <a:prstGeom prst="rect">
                                                        <a:avLst/>
                                                    </a:prstGeom>
                                                    <a:solidFill>
                                                        <a:srgbClr val="FFFFFF"/>
                                                    </a:solidFill>
                                                    <a:ln w="9525">
                                                        <a:solidFill>
                                                            <a:srgbClr val="000000"/>
                                                        </a:solidFill>
                                                        <a:miter lim="800000"/>
                                                        <a:headEnd/>
                                                        <a:tailEnd/>
                                                    </a:ln>
                                                </wps:spPr>
                                                <wps:txbx>
                                                    <w:txbxContent>
                                                        <w:p w:rsidR="00BD5B37" w:rsidRDefault="00BD5B37">
                                                            <w:proofErr w:type="spellStart"/>
                                                            <w:r>
                                                                <w:t>GetThisContent</w:t>
                                                            </w:r>
                                                            <w:proofErr w:type="spellEnd"/>
                                                        </w:p>
                                                    </w:txbxContent>
                                                </wps:txbx>
                                                <wps:bodyPr rot="0" vert="horz" wrap="square" lIns="91440" tIns="45720" rIns="91440" bIns="45720" anchor="t" anchorCtr="false">
                                                    <a:spAutoFit/>
                                                </wps:bodyPr>
                                            </wps:wsp>
                                        </a:graphicData>
                                    </a:graphic>
                                    <wp14:sizeRelH relativeFrom="margin">
                                        <wp14:pctWidth>40000</wp14:pctWidth>
                                    </wp14:sizeRelH>
                                    <wp14:sizeRelV relativeFrom="margin">
                                        <wp14:pctHeight>20000</wp14:pctHeight>
                                    </wp14:sizeRelV>
                                </wp:anchor>
                            </w:drawing>
                        </mc:Choice>
                        <mc:Fallback>
                            <w:pict>
                                <v:shapetype o:spt="202.0" path="m,l,21600r21600,l21600,xe" coordsize="21600,21600" id="_x0000_t202">
                                    <v:stroke joinstyle="miter"/>
                                    <v:path gradientshapeok="t" o:connecttype="rect"/>
                                </v:shapetype>
                                <v:shape o:gfxdata="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" type="#_x0000_t202" style="position:absolute;margin-left:-20.2pt;margin-top:0;width:185.9pt;height:110.6pt;z-index:251659264;visibility:visible;mso-wrap-style:square;mso-width-percent:400;mso-height-percent:200;mso-wrap-distance-left:9pt;mso-wrap-distance-top:3.6pt;mso-wrap-distance-right:9pt;mso-wrap-distance-bottom:3.6pt;mso-position-horizontal:absolute;mso-position-horizontal-relative:text;mso-position-vertical:absolute;mso-position-vertical-relative:text;mso-width-percent:400;mso-height-percent:200;mso-width-relative:margin;mso-height-relative:margin;v-text-anchor:top" id="Textfeld 2" o:spid="_x0000_s1026">
                                    <v:textbox style="mso-fit-shape-to-text:t">
                                        <w:txbxContent>
                                            <w:p w:rsidR="00BD5B37" w:rsidRDefault="00BD5B37">
                                                <w:proofErr w:type="spellStart"/>
                                                <w:r>
                                                    <w:t>GetThisContent</w:t>
                                                </w:r>
                                                <w:proofErr w:type="spellEnd"/>
                                            </w:p>
                                        </w:txbxContent>
                                    </v:textbox>
                                    <w10:wrap type="square"/>
                                </v:shape>
                            </w:pict>
                        </mc:Fallback>
                    </mc:AlternateContent>
                </w:r>
            </w:p>
            <w:sectPr w:rsidRPr="009670CB" w:rsidR="00CF457B" w:rsidSect="00BD5B37">
                <w:type w:val="continuous"/>
                <w:pgSz w:w="11907" w:h="8391" w:orient="landscape" w:code="11"/>
                <w:pgMar w:top="1418" w:right="1418" w:bottom="1418" w:left="1134" w:header="709" w:footer="709" w:gutter="0"/>
                <w:cols w:space="708"/>
                <w:docGrid w:linePitch="360"/>
            </w:sectPr>
        </w:body>
    </w:document>
```

I am using `"org.docx4j:docx4j-JAXB-ReferenceImpl:11.2.8"` in my build.gradle File if this is a relevant Information.

This is the important code now, I am selecting the run element like Jason told me, but I need to find out where i should add this and is this the only element I need to insert?
When I try to start the mail merge I get an exception that the r element is unexpected, because it's on the wrong position.

```
public static void main(final String[] args) throws Docx4JException, JAXBException
{
    final String filePath = "./files/GetTextfield.docx";
    
    final WordprocessingMLPackage word = Docx4J.load(new File(filePath));
    final MainDocumentPart document = word.getMainDocumentPart();
    
    final String xpathExpr = "//wps:txbx/w:txbxContent/w:p/w:r"; 
    final List<Object> nodes = document.getJAXBNodesViaXPath(xpathExpr, false);
    
    addPageBreak(document);
    
    final XmlUtils xmlUtils = new XmlUtils();
    final Object field = nodes.get(0);
    final Object copy = xmlUtils.deepCopy(field);
    
    document.addObject(copy);
    
    System.out.println(document.getXML());
    
    // TODO Before MailMerge need to copy template content to all pages
}
```

Comment: There are no "limits" in the free open source docx4j.  Please post the output of `document.getXML();`   Note that the docx format doesn't explicitly represent page layout.  You can add a second page if you inset a sectPr of type next page before the content of the first page spills over.

Comment: Thank you for you answer and trying to help me! :)
I have updated my post with this information, I already have implemented this method from you for adding a page break. (https://stackoverflow.com/a/28887618/13163366)

But if there is a better way to add pages I'm open for implementing this :)

Comment: You can add a page break that way, or using a sectPr element.

Comment: You can see from getXML that there are contents.  So do you still have issues with document.getContents() or document.getContent()?

Comment: To clone an object (eg your r object), use the deepCopy method:  https://github.com/plutext/docx4j/blob/master/docx4j-core/src/main/java/org/docx4j/XmlUtils.java#L1083  Note though that things are sometimes not so simple though, for example where there are external rels.   Here, you may need to ensure that wp:docPr/@id is unique

Comment: Yes i don't find any element with getContent, i get an emty list. 
I'm trying to implement all this. I found out that when I want to use org.w3c.dom.Node, but imported docx4j-export-fo:11.2.8 in my gradle file that this will result in an module problem . https://stackoverflow.com/q/57286825/13163366

Comment: A w:r should be inside a w:p.

Comment: The "document as XML" above, how are you creating that?

Comment: As a general comment, this question probably isn't  a good fit for StackOverflow because there are too many things going on in it.  Perhaps you should create separate questions, for example, "why is my content list empty"?

Comment: It is inside and I got the XML with document.getXML().
Okay I created a new Post, should I delete this one? 
https://stackoverflow.com/q/67364630/13163366

Comment: @JasonPlutext I don't want to stress you but can you maybe take a look at the new post?